# TrafficLight using SetTImeout and ReactHooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout

```
const lightDurations = [ 5000, 2000, 1000];

const TrafficLight = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [colorIndex, setColorIndex] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setColorIndex((colorIndex + 1) % 3);
    }, lightDurations[colorIndex]);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="traffic-light">
      <Light color="#f00" active={colorIndex === 0} />
      <Light color="#ff0" active={colorIndex === 2} />
      <Light color="#0c0" active={colorIndex === 1} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

The code works perfectly. It is just a traffic light that changes its color. But I need at first the three lights to be active for five seconds and only once. I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an additional state variable that represents if the TrafficLight is working or it is in sort of initial state. Then you just need to switch this state in the similar way you do it for `colorIndex`.

```
const initialDelay = 5000;

const TrafficLight = ({ initialValue }) => {
  const [colorIndex, setColorIndex] = useState(initialValue);
  const [isStarted, setIsStarted] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setIsStarted(true);
    }, initialDelay);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  }, []); // note [] - it makes it run once

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isStarted) {
      return;
    }
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      setColorIndex((colorIndex + 1) % 3);
    }, lightDurations[colorIndex]);
    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    };
  });

  return (
    <div className="traffic-light">
      <Light color="#f00" active={!isStarted || colorIndex === 0} />
      <Light color="#ff0" active={!isStarted || colorIndex === 2} />
      <Light color="#0c0" active={!isStarted || colorIndex === 1} />
    </div>
  );
};
```